# Access internal method of jquery plugin ResponsiveSlides.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow

I'm trying to understand a basic javascript : how can I access an inner method of a plugin, after it was attached to an element of the DOM ?

Basically, after doing...

```
var $div = $('#slideshow .rslides').responsiveSlides({
    speed:1000,
    timeout:4000,
    pager:true,
    pause:true
});
```

... with the following plugin : https://github.com/viljamis/ResponsiveSlides.js , can I call this plugins'

```
    slideTo = function (idx) {
      settings.before();
      $slide
        .stop()
        .fadeOut(fadeTime, function () {
          $(this)
            .removeClass(visibleClass)
            .css(hidden);
        })
        .eq(idx)
        .fadeIn(fadeTime, function () {
          $(this)
            .addClass(visibleClass)
            .css(visible);
          settings.after();
          index = idx;
        });
    };
```

method line 73 ? Thanks for the help and time, a lot.

Comment: Did you try something like this: `$div.slideTo(3);` where 3 is the index you want to slide to.

Comment: Are you familiar with JavaScript's [function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Nested_functions_and_closures)? Unfortunately it will tell you the short answer is: No.

Comment: possible duplicate with answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594790/trigger-responsiveslides-js-programmatically