# Trigger ResponsiveSlides.js programmatically

Tags: jquery, triggers, responsive-slides

I'm using [ResponsiveSlides.js](http://responsive-slides.viljamis.com/) and I am trying to change slides programmatically. I've tried it two ways, and neither have worked.

1. Calling the plugin's **slideTo** function from a click event on the thumbnail, passing the index of the slide it should go to.
2. Use `.trigger("click")` on the `<li>` corresponding to the index of the slide it should go to, ex:

   $(".rslides_tabs li").eq($theIndex).trigger("click");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't call the `slideTo()` function because it is assigned only to a local variable in the plugin method.

Your second attempt was close, but it looks like the click handler is bound to an `<a>` element.

Try:

```
$('.rslides_tabs').find('a').eq(index).trigger('click');
```

Where `index` is the zero-based index of the slide you want to show.

Note: If you passed a value in for the "namespace" option, then you would have to change the class name from "rslides_tabs" to whatever value you passed + "_tabs". So if you passed `( namespace: 'mynamespace' }` for the options, the class would be "mynamespace_tabs".

Comment: Adding that a did it. Too many hours staring at code.  Thanks!